# include php code inside an echo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation-menu' ) ); ?>
```

between this div,

`<div class="right"></div>`

of below code. This whole HTML code is currently outputs by `<?php echo ?>`

This is what I used,

```
<?php
echo '<div class="top-box-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Search bar
        </div>
        <div class="right"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation-menu' ) ); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>'; ?>
```

But it doesn't work when I put the php code inside the `<div></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<div class="top-box-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Search bar
        </div>
        <div class="right">' . wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation-menu' ) ) . '</div>
    </div>
</div>'; ?>
```

Have a look at [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in the PHP Documentation.